# Lookup value between non-continuous range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I tried and tried but can't get to a solution.

I have a dataset which is about 80k long with "MPL" values (column A). 
The MPL value in Column "A" could be: 55000, 45000, 46000.

Then I have a mapping sheet with ranges.
E.g. 
MPL 50000 to 59999 is called "Hull" 
MPL 40000 to 40199 is called "Marine"
MPL 44230 to 46000 is called "Air"

What formula could I use in column "B" (in the data set next to column "A") to map the codes to the Name?
Unfortunately I cant attach Image or Spreadsheet.. so I have to explain it like this...
Thanks

Comment: you can post screen shots on Imgur and then paste the link.  Please [edit] the code to show those.  It is hard to follow what you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate a table with your code like this:

[image]

(notice you must add `1` to the upper bound of each code range)

2. The following formula will return the name corresponding to whatever code is in column `A`:

   ```
   =INDEX(G$2:G$9,MATCH(A2,F$2:F$9,1)+1)
   ```

However it returns `0` when the code has no corresponding name (ex.: if the code is `25000`) so wrapping it in an `IF` statement fixes this:

```
=IF(INDEX(G$2:G$9,MATCH(A2,F$2:F$9,1)+1)=0,"",INDEX(G$2:G$9,MATCH(A2,F$2:F$9,1)+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Lookup Table in `D1:F5` (adjust the table range in meet with you needed)

[image]

In `B2`, enter formula and copied down :

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,0/($D$3:$D$5<=A2)/($E$3:$E$5>=A2),$F$3:$F$5),"Not found")
```